# Картинка, подстраивающаяся под размер окна

Tags: qt, qml

Здравствуйте! Есть приложение на qt, хотелось бы при запуске несколько секунд показывать картинку (лого и название). Как сделать так, чтобы эта картинка подстроилась под размер экрана?

Answer (score 1):

Для получения размера экрана попробуйте использовать `QDesktopWidget`:

```
QRect rect = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
int h = rect.height();
int w = rect.width();
```